# AWS Lambda using Image Container cannot find handler export

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Using Serverless AWS Lambda Image containers but it cannot find the handler.

Serverless forces me:

- to use a command when using an image
- to use a relative path to my handler in my command

#### serverless.yml (v3.25.0)

```
service: example-service
 
provider:
  name: aws
  ecr:
    images:
      appimage:
        path: ./
        file: Dockerfile
        platform: linux/arm64
 
functions:
  getDocument:
    image:
      command:
        - src/function/getDocument/index.handler
      entryPoint:
        - '/lambda-entrypoint.sh'
      name: appimage
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:12
 
COPY src/function/getDocument/index.ts ./

CMD ["index.handler"]
```

#### error

```
"errorType":"Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
"errorMessage":"src/function/getDocument/index.handler is undefined or not exported",
"stack":["Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported", "at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)"
```

I'm not sure how UserFunction.js fits into this.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for my unique setup using webpack.

I needed to

1. build the getDocument function (serverless package)
2. copy the build files into my container (Dockerfile)
3. deploy that function to aws (serverless deploy)
4. change my command from 'src/function/getDocument/index.handler' to 'index.handler' through the aws management console (website)

#### serverless.yml

```
service: example-service
 
provider:
  name: aws
  ecr:
    images:
      appimage:
        path: ./
        file: Dockerfile
        platform: linux/arm64
 
functions:
  getDocument:
    image:
      command:
        - src/function/getDocument/index.handler
      entryPoint:
        - '/lambda-entrypoint.sh'
      name: appimage
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14

RUN yum -y upgrade
RUN yum -y install YOUR_PACKAGES
 
COPY build/getDocument/index.js build/getDocument/index.js.map ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN npm add text2png

CMD ["index.handler"]
```